# Excel : Sum number of hours worked per day with date + time format

Tags: excel, sumifs, hour

I'd like to sum number of hours worked per resource per day.

Example :

```
Resource | Task Duration (hours) | Start Date/Time | End Date/Time
-------- | --------------------  | --------------- | -------------
John     | 2:00                  | 27/09/16 14:00  | 27/09/16 16:00
John     | 2:00                  | 27/09/16 16:00  | 27/09/16 18:00
Mary     | 2:00                  | 03/10/16 09:00  | 03/10/16 11:00
```

What I would like to retrieve is the following :

```
Resource |    Day    | Hours 
-------- | --------- | ------
John     | 27/09/16  | 4
Mary     | 03/10/16  | 2
```

I tried with SUMIFS function but 27/09/16 is 42640 when converted to number while 27/09/2016  14:00:00 is 42640,5833333333 so it does not match.

I'm looking for a formula to match with the first 5 numbers that is the day, regardless the time.

Can you help please ?

Thanks.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a SUMPRODUCT variation

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INT($C$2:$C$4)=G2),--($A$2:$A$4=F2),$B$2:$B$4*24)
```

[image]

I tried SUMIFS with INT, but for some reason Excel does not accept that. I  don't know the reason .

Comment: I tried both solutions, they all work : thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIFS(), You just need to bracket the date:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;H2;C:C;">=" & I2;C:C;"<"&I2+1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried both solutions, they all work : thanks a lot !